# How can I compare two arrays with alphanumeric elements?

Tags: perl

I have two arrays that I want to compare

```
 @array1 = ( aaa, bbb, aaabbb, aaa23bbb, ddd555, 430hd9789);

 @array2 = ( 34322hh2, jjfjr78, uuu7shv, ddd555, hjkdjroo);
```

I have to compare these two arrays and find duplicate and do something about it.

Conditions:

1. Length of each element in array can be different. There is no such fixed pattern.
2. Elements can be just numeric i.e. 334343, or just char i.e. "somewordexample", or it can alphanumeric i.e. wewe83493
3. There can be more such elements in the array.

Now I know the following about comparison operators `==` and `eq`:

`==` is for comparing numbers

`eq` is for string comparison

How can I compare alphanumeric values?

This is my code so far

```
for (my $i = 0 ; $i <= $#array1 ; $i++ ) {
  for (my $j = 0 ; $j <= $#array2 ; $j++ ) {
    if ( $array1[$i] == $arra2[$j] ) {
      print "duplicate";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [List::Compare](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Compare) is your friend.

Comment: Please show the Perl code you have tried, and explain what problems you are having.

Comment: And alphanumeric value is a string. Therefore, you use the string comparison operators.

Answer (score 3):

You manner is indolent, and you seem to be looking for a quick fix without caring whether you understand the solution. The posts on Stack Overflow are primarily for people other than the originator who may have a similar problem.

You should read [`perlfaq4`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq.html#the-perlfaq4-manpage:-Data-Manipulation). Specifically:

- `perldoc -q intersection` - *"How do I compute the difference of two arrays? How do I compute the intersection of two arrays?"*
- `perldoc -q contained` - *"How can I tell whether a certain element is contained in a list or array?"*
- `perldoc -q duplicate` - *"How can I remove duplicate elements from a list or array?"*

Comment: __dad is mad!!__ ... +1 for the precise links to Q&A.

Comment: I clearly mentioned in my question that I used eq or == ?
What part of that you didn't understand ? 

Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @jaypal: Thanks. I'm sorry, but it infuriates me the number of people who post a question here who are clearly looking for someone to do their work for them without having made any effort of their own. As well as being damn rude, an answer posted here is rarely a simple copy/paste plugin to the real situation, and without having studied the issue at all the OP will have little chance of applying the answer to their problem. Then another post comes up, and so on. There are many chains of question just like that. A good answer conveys a *concept* and not just a string of characters.

Comment: @Borodin _A good answer conveys a concept and not just a string of characters._ I couldn't agree more ...

Comment: @Borodin Sorry I didn't mean to be rude at all. I get what you are saying. Cheers,

Comment: @JohnF: Dear John. I understood it all. Completely. The problem is that there was very little of it. Saying that you (half) understand the difference between `eq` and `==` is just a fraction of the problem you were facing. It turns out that you knew to iterate over the indices of the two arrays, but not how to do that best, nor how to use the other points in my final answer. If you have written *anything* then *please show it*, together with a description of the problems you are having. It isn't just me who gets weary of people who come straight to Stack Overflow without having written a thing

Comment: @Borodin Yes, I was close. You are write. I should have posted the code. Lesson Learned. :D 
cheers,

Comment: @JohnF: Yes, your ideas were right. Your original post seemed to say that you knew about `eq` and `==` and not much else; hence my ire. As long as you have an idea of what you need to do, and have the wherewithal to attempt an implementation, then your failures are the bread and butter of this site and you are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for posting your misbehaving code.

There are a few problems

- You must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program, and declare each variable as close as possible to its first point of use. That simple measure will reveal many faults for you that you may otherwise overlook
- I have used `qw` to define the array data
- It is much better to use the Perl `foreach` than the C-style `for`
- As you appear to have discovered, the `==` operator is for comparing numbers. You have strings so you need `eq`

Apart from that, all I have changed in your code is to mention the text of the duplicate entry instead of just printing *"duplicate"*

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array1 = qw( aaa bbb aaabbb aaa23bbb ddd555 430hd9789 );

my @array2 = qw( 34322hh2 jjfjr78 uuu7shv ddd555 hjkdjroo );

for my $i (0 .. $#array1) {
  for my $j (0 .. $#array2) {
    if ( $array1[$i] eq $array2[$j] ) {
      print "Duplicate '$array1[$i]'\n";
    }
  }
}
```

**output**

```
Duplicate 'ddd555'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your alphanumeric values can still be treated as strings. If you want to find elements that are in both your lists, you can use the `get_intersection` function provided by the [List::Compare](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Compare) module:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Compare;

my @array1 = qw(aaa bbb aaabbb aaa23bbb ddd555 430hd9789);
my @array2 = qw(34322hh2 jjfjr78 uuu7shv ddd555 hjkdjroo);

my $comp = List::Compare->new(\@array1, \@array2);
my @duplicates = $comp->get_intersection();

if (@duplicates > 0) {
    print "@duplicates\n";
}
```

Output:

```
ddd555
```

Answer (score 1):

Alphanumeric values are just strings. Numeric values are a subset of those that Perl considers to be numeric (i.e. Scalar::Util::looks_like_number() returns true). In this case, you could use `eq` or any other string-related function for comparison (such as the less commonly used `index`).

To find exact duplicates in O(n) time

```
my %seen;
for my $duplicate (grep { ++$seen{$_} > 1 } (@array1, @array2))
{
    # Do what you need to do to the duplicates
}
```

If you just want to get rid of the elements of @array1 that are duplicated in @array2,

```
my %seen = map { $_ => 1 } @array2;
@array1 = grep { not $seen{$_} } @array1;
```

Comment: Your first solution effectively makes three scans of the values. The example of the second code fragment is all that is needed. In this case `my %s = map {$_,1} @array1; say $_ for grep $s{$_}, @array2;` does the trick

Comment: @Borodin Thanks, wasn't sure what I was thinking when I wrote that. I rectified the first snippet. The fixed version is also slightly more efficient than the one you suggested (at least on my machine).

Comment: Stack Overflow - in my mind at least - is about providing a *permanent* library of solutions to programming problems. With that in mind, focusing entirely on the question at hand is tempting but counter-productive. I'm afraid the battle for experience points encourages the wrong sort of answer, but I also think there would be far too few answers without the carrot of competition. Most of all I wish my comment didn't make you think you should amend your answer. Any answer, taken in context, is a useful answer. It is always good to see how others fail, as well as how they succeed.

Comment: @Borodin Funny you should say that--I have a file of short, useful snippets of code for common tasks that I collected when I first started learning Perl, and the first example was my (erroneous) attempt at remembering a specific idiom. Your comment brought the mistake to my attention. Sorry if my previous comment came off as being competitive; the edit was more to make the answer more faithful to the example in my personal "permanent library of solutions". I did the benchmark out of curiosity and mentioned the result without considering that it might appear 'one-uppish'.

Comment: Pending an epiphany there will always be a tension between answering the question at hand and building an encyclopaedia of programming knowledge. You are very far from being the worst offender, and I do the same thing myself daily.

Answer (score -2):

you can do this using exact matching regex:

if("4lph4" =~ /^4lph4$/)
{ .... }

Comment: You mean making regex for each of the element in one of the array and then match it ? 

I Have 100 elements in each array. Would you mind doing it for me ? :P

Comment: no i mean something like this:

my @a = ("test1","test2","test3");
my @b = ("test2","test3","test4");
foreach my $e1 (@a)
{
foreach my $e2 (@b)
{
if ($e1 =~ /^$e2$/)
{
print "$e1 match $e2\n";
}
else{
print "$e1 don't match $e2\n";
}
}
}

Comment: @JohnF: For goodness sake man. Would you mind making a bit of effort yourself?

Comment: @Borodin I tried iterating both the arrays with == and eq but i dont know how to compare alphanumeric values. 
The error is I cannot compare two elements with either == or eq

Comment: @JohnF: Please post what you tried and explain the problem.

Comment: `for (my $i = 0 ; $i <= $#array1 ; $i++ )
 { 
   for (my $j = 0 ; $j <= $#array2 ; $j++ )
    {
      if ( $array1[$i] == $arra2[$j] )
      {
         print "duplicate";
       }
    }
}`

Get the idea ? 

Although, Compare is what iwas looking for!

Comment: @JohnF Please don't post code in your comments. Borodin's intention is good. All he is asking for is to add whatever you tried in your question. It doesn't have to be a working code else why you'd be here anyways. Sometimes you are closer to the solution than you think ...

Comment: @JohnF: Okay I have put your code into the question for you. It would be nice if you explained what was wrong with it, but I'll try to work with that.

Comment: Please could explain why my method is wrong for you ? cause it worked for me, is there's any danger in using it ?
thanks.

Comment: I think copying your first comment into your answer would make sense. @user2676847 You also might want to format part of your answer as code (by selecting a part of your answer and clicking the `{}` button).